# Does the size of the cap booster affect the shield boost bonus?

Tags: eve-online

Do the sizes of the Cap Booster charges used in an Ancillary Shield Booster affect the shield boost amount, or only the cycle time? I've been using Cap Booster 400s in my Large ASB for some time now, but I've noticed that 50s and 100s appear to rep the same amount, but cycle faster. Am I just seeing things here, or is this how its supposed to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, the size of the charge has absolutely no effect. Always use the smallest possible charge for Ancillary Shield Boosters.

Comment: I haven't used cap boosters much myself, but this advice differs from that of experienced players on the Eve Uni forum. The size of the the charges influences how much cap charge can be gotten from one pulse of the booster, and the average rate at which the cap can be recharged. Bigger charges = faster average recharge rate, and the conclusion is "use the biggest that will fit." And preferably use the faction version.

Comment: @wades You are completely correct for the use of cap charges in Capacitor Boosters. However, this question is about Ancillary Shield Boosters.

Answer (score 5):

It does not matter which size of the Cap Booster charges you use, but there is a difference between regular and Navy Cap Boosters. From the [Retribution patch notes](http://community.eveonline.com/news/patch-notes/patch-notes-for-retribution-1):

> Reduced capacity – 7 regular booster or 9 navy boosters.

So you should always use the smallest charge that fits, and preferably the Navy version unless you're on a very tight budget.